# One time login crashing in iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, crash, master-detail

I have a requirement wherein i have to do one time login feature.If i have set functionality enabled then i have to move to home page which is a master detail page and if it is off then i have to go to login page.
But while setting master detail page as main page i am getting this error-
"Master and Detail must be set before adding MasterDetailPage to a container"
   This is my app.xaml.cs code

```
 protected override void OnInitialized()

{

InitializeComponent();

if(Application.Current.Properties.Key.Contains("IsSet")
{
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MenuPage/NavigationPage/HomePage");
}
else
{
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("LoginPage");
}
```

where menupage is my master detail page.

Comment: The exception which i get is   this  UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");

Comment: Is your login page works fine on iOS?

Comment: yes login works fine

Comment: Then you have to try with just HomePage instead of that path.

Comment: That path is nothing but i am trying to call my master details page.If i will call only home page my master details page will not come